# Retaining color changes done by buttons between different html pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a site where a button is used to change the CSS colour scheme to dark using;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".theme-switch").on("click", () => {
    $("body").toggleClass("dark-theme");
  });
});
```

Which changes colour variables within CSS which in turn changes the colour scheme of that specific page. But how can I retain that colour change throughout my whole site?

Comment: Save it in `localstorage` and read it on every page load and apply the class to the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save that and access that later on you can do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  let darkTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'dark';
  updateTheme();

  function updateTheme() {
      if (darkTheme) {
          $("body").addClass("dark-theme");
      } else {
          $("body").removeClass("dark-theme");
      }
  }

  $(".theme-switch").on("click", () => {
      darkTheme = !darkTheme;
      updateTheme();
      localStorage.setItem('theme', darkTheme ? 'dark' : 'light');
  });
});
```

You can also add this to ensure that it changes across all the tabs:

```js
window.addEventListener('storage', () => {
     darkTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'dark';
     updateTheme();
});
```

(before `function updateTheme()`). The `storage` event gets fired any time `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` is updated in another tab for your domain. It is useful for communication between tabs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But if I were to have multiple pages run by the same CSS stylesheet, how would I save the variable on localStorage so that other pages use the same new colour variables assigned in the page which originally had the button.

Comment: You can't use the same localStorage across multiple domains. This would be only possible with an account system and back end storage.

Comment: The other solution would be to host a JS script on one domain that would take care of saving the localStorage and importing it with `<script src="">`, not sure how well that would work though.

Comment: So, that would mean that the local storage of `site.com/index.html` is different from `site.com/other.html`

Comment: Not like that. `site.com` is the domain, so it wouldn't be different.

Comment: Ahh, that's what I meant by pages before. But, how is it that you access the localStorage of `/index.html` from `/other.html` so that you can keep the same css color variables between them

Comment: Just use the same exact code. Nothing changes if you stay within the same domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Like Carlton suggests you can add the logic to the localStorage or alternatively sessionStorage depending on how long you want the information to persist.
More information on the difference between localStorage and sessionStorage here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage
But you can simply do this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".theme-switch").on("click", () => {
    var theme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
    if(theme == null || theme != 'dark') {
      localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
    }
    $("body").toggleClass("dark-theme");
  });

  var theme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
  if(theme == 'dark') {
    $("body").addClass('dark-theme');
  } else {
    $("body").removeClass('dark-theme');
  }
});
```